corroded contacts cured with WD40?
Does WD40 help fix corroded contacts in a plug or does it risk shorting them?
The airbag warning light in my car is on and I intend to fix it by squirting WD40 down the pug and socket.

I wouldn't. You want deoxit, most likely.

Relevant: How does WD-40 remove rust? on chemistry se
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/77432/how-does-wd-40-remove-rust

And also: How does WD40 displace water?
chemsitry se https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50741/how-does-wd40-displace-water

A relevant question is will WD40 melt or soften the plastics?  You don't even know if the warning light is due to corroded contacts or something else like a broken wire.

Make sure to follow the instructions regarding disconnecting the airbag very carefully otherwise it can operate accidentally. What makes you think that corrosion is the problem?

WD 40 is a desiccant it does nothing more than remove water which is useful for some types of corrosion. Buffer from all types of corrosion it does nothing you need contact cleaner like deoxit or other type of contact cleaner that actually gets rid of the corrosion.
Corrosion is usually oxidation so you need something that can remove the oxygen, not just the water.
